# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhausCompiled with warnings

Tags: redux, react-redux, eslint, middleware, redux-thunk

Error while dispatching an action!

**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhausCompiled with warnings.**

[image]
App.js :-

```
function App() {
  const user = null;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
        dispatch(login({
          uid: userAuth.uid,
          email: userAuth.email
        }));
      } else {
        dispatch(logout);
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

userSlice.js :-

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    }
  },
  logout: (state) => {
    state.user = null;
  }
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;
```

store.js :-

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: If you want to remove the warning of useEffect missing the dependency dispatch, then add it as a dependency. useEffect(() => ... , [dispatch])

Comment: But the screenshot you posted is a different error. It's saying that `logout` is undefined, when it should be an object. Is it? How are you importing it?

Comment: This is how I've imported logout - 
import { login, logout } from './features/userSlice';

Comment: How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: According to the front page https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice shouldn't logout be inside the reducers object?

Comment: Yes, I made the mistake there... Thanks for pointing out!